# .htaccess in mediawiki not working

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki, wiki

I have a wiki up and running at example.com.
when you go to the page the links change in the URL to /index.php/Main_Page

I do not want the parts after / for the main page.  Also want the index.php out

I have this currently in my `.htaccess`

```
rewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ wiki/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ wiki/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ wiki/index.php [L,QSA]
```

and this in my Localsettings.

```
$wgScriptPath       = "/w";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
```

Where is my error?  I cannot figure it out ... I followed the mediawiki to the T.

Answer (score 0):

Your three rewrite rules are contradictory and don't match your $wgScriptPath. You probably meant something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/wiki/(.*)$ w/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ w/index.php [L,QSA]
```

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache for more.